# XCode and iPhone Compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to test apps on my physical iPhone 12. Currently, it says that it failed to prepare the device for development. I've tried to restart the phone like people reccommend, but it didn't work.

The iOS of the iPhone is 15.4.1, and the XCode version is 13.2.1. I'm thinking that they might not be compatible. Are they?

Comment: Have you tested on this device before?

Comment: I'd try rebooting the Mac as well and making sure to use the latest stable macOS and Xcode versions.

Comment: Also, if you have an Apple Watch paired with the phone, try shutting down the watch for the sake of the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com), Xcode 13.2.1 ships with the iOS 15.2 SDK so it won't work out of the box with an iOS device running iOS 15.4.

Xcode 13.3 supports iOS 15.4 but requires macOS 12. If your Mac can't run macOS 12, you can find iOS support files for iOS 15.4 and add them to your Xcode app bundle. You can find more detailed information in the following article:

[Dealing with "Failed to prepare device for development" Error Message in Xcode](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/dealing-with-failed-to-prepare-device-for-development-error-message-in-xcode/)